# How to limit a query's results to only duplicates?

Tags: sql, group-by, duplicates, mysql-workbench, having

This is probably a dumb question, but it's got me stumped.  I'm basically using 3 tables to pull Campaign and Team details (below).

```
SELECT      GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID,
            TEAM.ID,
            TEAM.NAME
FROM        CAMPAIGN_ANALYTICS_GOLD GOLD
LEFT JOIN   ENTITY ENT
ON          ENT.CAMPAIGN_ID = GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID
LEFT JOIN   TEAM TEAM
ON          TEAM.ID = ENT.TEAM_ID
GROUP BY    GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID,
            GOLD.CAMPAIGN_NAME,
            TEAM.ID,
            TEAM.NAME;
```

I'm able to map out what Campaigns are aligned to which Teams, but I want to filter the results only for those Campaigns which are mapped to multiple Teams.  For example, this is what some of the results look like:

```
CAMPAIGN_ID    ID           NAME
830            65           Media Group APAC
917            40           iAdvertising
1133           9            Media Comp
1133           2            Ad Network 5
7163           931          Y Vector
8149           318          Hectic Media
8149           3827         Effective Media Net
15982          1919         ADCMP 10
27587          2675         MediaCorp NA
27587          48           North Shore Ad
```

What do I need to add to my query in order to determine those Campaign IDs which are mapped to multiple teams (in this example, 1133, 8149, and 27587), or what would be the best practice in order to achieve these results?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with an inner join on so that you will filter on the rows that you want to get.

**Edit:** This query assumes that there can be only one row in the `ENTITY` table with the same `CAMPAIGN_ID` and `TEAM_ID` pair. If you could have duplicates rows, then I think that you should look at the solution provided by John Bollinger.

```
SELECT      GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID,
            TEAM.ID,
            TEAM.NAME
FROM        CAMPAIGN_ANALYTICS_GOLD GOLD
LEFT JOIN   ENTITY ENT
ON          ENT.CAMPAIGN_ID = GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID
LEFT JOIN   TEAM TEAM
ON          TEAM.ID = ENT.TEAM_ID
INNER JOIN 
(

SELECT      CAMPAIGN_ID
FROM        ENTITY
GROUP BY    CAMPAIGN_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

) x on x.G_ID= GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID
GROUP BY    GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID,
            GOLD.CAMPAIGN_NAME,
            TEAM.ID,
            TEAM.NAME;
```

Comment: That would identify campaigns with multiple `entity`s, but it could produce unwanted extra results if multiple `entity`s were assigned to the same campaign and team.  Whether that needs to be accounted for depends on the data.

Comment: @John Bollinger: Your right. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL then you don't have access to analytic functions, which otherwise would provide a very convenient solution (per @JohnOdom).  In that case you also don't have access to common table expressions, which would be convenient.

If it is safe to assume that no two distinct entities associated with the same team will ever be associated with the same campaign, then the problem can be reduced to identifying campaigns associated with multiple associated entities, for which @user707727 provided a solution.

A more general solution is a bit more complicated, but you can at least make some assumptions.  In particular, a campaign can be associated with multiple teams only via association with existing entities and their existing teams, therefore you can perform inner joins instead of outer joins.  Moreover, note that *all* the information about which teams are associated with which campaigns is carried by table `entity` alone, so queries probing that relationship need consider only that table.

The following solution first identifies the wanted (`campaign_id`, `team_id`) pairs by analysis of only table `ENTITY`, then joins table `TEAM` to get the team name.  Table `campaign` could also be joined in the outer query if other information about the campaign (e.g. its name) were desired.  Supposing that `campaign_id` and `team_id` are the PKs of their respective tables, no grouping is required at the top level.

```
SELECT
  CAMP_TEAM.CAMPAIGN_ID,
  TEAM.ID,
  TEAM.NAME
FROM
  (
    (
      SELECT CAMPAIGN_ID
      FROM ENTITY
      GROUP BY CAMPAIGN_ID
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TEAM_ID) > 1
    ) CAMP
    JOIN ENTITY ENT
      ON ENT.CAMPAIGN_ID = CAMP.CAMPAIGN_ID
    GROUP BY ENT.CAMPAIGN_ID, ENT.TEAM_ID
  ) CAMP_TEAM
  JOIN TEAM TEAM
    ON TEAM.ID = CAMP_TEAM.TEAM_ID
;
```

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE] I guess I'm a noob at MYSQL thinking it is like MSSQL Lol :P. But I have now updated my answer to be compliant with MYSQL. You can check my SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21c968/24).

You can use `COUNT(CAMPAIGN_ID)` with `GROUP BY CAMPAIGN_ID` to get the total number of rows grouped by `CAMPAIGN_ID` (meaning rows that have the same CAMPAIGN_ID, hence duplicates) then filter where the counts that are greater than 1. There are different ways to do this but here is my favorite way:

```
SELECT tt.CAMPAIGN_ID, tt.ID, tt.NAME
FROM
(
    SELECT GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID,
           TEAM.ID,
           TEAM.NAME,
           COUNT(GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID) as [Count]
     FROM  CAMPAIGN_ANALYTICS_GOLD GOLD
     LEFT JOIN ENTITY ENT ON ENT.CAMPAIGN_ID = GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID
     LEFT JOIN TEAM TEAM ON TEAM.ID = ENT.TEAM_ID
     GROUP BY GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID
) t
INNER JOIN CAMPAIGN_ANALYTICS_GOLD GOLD ON GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID = t.CAMPAIGN_ID
WHERE t.Count > 1
```

I did not know the layout of your tables so I made a test table with the same results that you posted then created the query to only return duplicates on my SQL Fiddle link.

Here is my MSSQL version of the answer for future viewers:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID,
           TEAM.ID,
           TEAM.NAME,
           COUNT(GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID) as [Count]
    FROM  CAMPAIGN_ANALYTICS_GOLD GOLD
    LEFT JOIN ENTITY ENT ON ENT.CAMPAIGN_ID = GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID
    LEFT JOIN TEAM TEAM ON TEAM.ID = ENT.TEAM_ID
    GROUP BY GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID, GOLD.CAMPAIGN_NAME, TEAM.ID, TEAM.NAME
) t
WHERE t.Count > 1
```

And the MSSQL SQL Fiddle link [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21c96/3).

If you still want the results to be unique incase there are duplicate rows (campaign, id, and name) then you can add the `DISTINCT` clause to the outer select statements of either queries.

Comment: He tagged mysql-workbench, so it seems reasonable to suppose he's using mysql.  Unfortunately, mysql is notable among major DBMSs for *not* supporting analytic functions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I updated my answer to work with MYSQL.

Comment: The new query has the same problem that @user707727's has (which might not be a problem at all, depending on the data): it can produce false positives in the event that a campaign is associated with the same team via two distinct entities.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't understand what you mean by `false positives in the event that a campaign is associated with the same team via two distinct entities.` Could you give sample data of what you are talking about?

Comment: The problem is to filter for campaigns associated with more than one team.  It is not clear whether there can be two distinct entity rows having the same `campaign_id` and the same `team_id` as each other, but suppose there indeed are two that have `campaign_id` 2 and `team_id` 1, and that no other entities have `campaign_id` 2.  Prior to grouping, your join will then contain one row for *each* of those two entities, so the `COUNT()` for that group will be 2, and it will pass the filter.  It is not among the desired results, however, because it's associated with only team 1.

Answer (score 1):

the group by eliminates the left so just go with a join

```
SELECT      GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID,
            TEAM.ID,
            TEAM.NAME
FROM        CAMPAIGN_ANALYTICS_GOLD GOLD 
JOIN        ENT
  ON        ENT.CAMPAIGN_ID = GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID
JOIN        TEAM 
  ON        TEAM.ID = ENT.TEAM_ID 

JOIN        CAMPAIGN_ANALYTICS_GOLD GOLDdup 
  ON        GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID = GOLDdup.CAMPAIGN_ID  
JOIN        ENT as ENTdup
  ON        ENTdup.CAMPAIGN_ID = GOLDdup.CAMPAIGN_ID
 and        ENTdup.TempID <> ENT.TEAM_ID  -- this finds the dups

GROUP BY    GOLD.CAMPAIGN_ID,
            GOLD.CAMPAIGN_NAME,
            TEAM.ID,
            TEAM.NAME;
```